# MPI hello world is not reading processes correctly

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm having trouble getting the correct number of processes to output on a hello world program. I'm fairly certain this program should work since it was provided by the textbook that we are using. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mpi.h>

const int MAX_STRING = 100;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char greeting[MAX_STRING];
    int comm_sz;
    int my_rank;

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_sz);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

   if (my_rank != 0)
   {
       sprintf(greeting, "Greetings from process %d of %d!\n", my_rank, comm_sz);
       MPI_Send(greeting, strlen(greeting)+1, MPI_CHAR, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   }
   else
   {
       printf("Greetings from process %d of %d!\n", my_rank, comm_sz);
       for (int q = 1; q < comm_sz; q++)
       {
           MPI_Recv(greeting, MAX_STRING, MPI_CHAR, q, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
           printf("%s\n", greeting);
       }
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling it by running

```
mpicxx hello_mpi.cpp -O3
```

Which compiles fine, then I execute it by

```
mpiexec -n 4 ./a.out
```

Using 4 as an example number of threads. I should be receiving an output as

```
Greetings from process 0 of 4!
Greetings from process 1 of 4!
Greetings from process 2 of 4!
Greetings from process 3 of 4!
```

But instead I am getting

```
Greetings from process 0 of 1!
Greetings from process 0 of 1!
Greetings from process 0 of 1!
Greetings from process 0 of 1!
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this result instead of a rank from each thread. Again, this was the code provided by the textbook we are using (although originally written in C, I tried compiling an executing in C but ran into the same error).

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't the `MPI_Init` call be `MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);`?

Comment: It can, but since the program wasn't using these arguments I just passed in NULL. Either way, I changed it, saved and recompiled but it's still the same issue.

Comment: Which MPI library are you using?

Comment: mpiexec (OpenRTE) 1.6.5. I'm wondering if maybe the MPI version is outdated. I downloaded it through sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin